# Why will my JSON file only update 1 field at a time?

Tags: php, json

The code below, When I click the 'Update Button' it updates a certain field in my JSON file, the problem is:

**Problem:** When I fill in more than 1 field, then click update, nothing will be updated in the JSON file. I don't know why this is happening. If I fill in only 1 field at the time then click update, the JSON file will be updated, but anymore than 1 field at a time, the JSON wont be updated.

**Desired Result:** Be able to fill out multiple fields at the same time, then click the update button and the changed fields will have updated.

Source Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['update'])){
    
    foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['userID'] == $_SESSION['userID']) {
            if(!empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
                $decode[$key]['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
            }
            elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['username'])){
                $decode[$key]['username'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
            }
            elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['password'])){
                $decode[$key]['password'] = sha1($_REQUEST['password']);
            }
            elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['account'])){
                $decode[$key]['account_type'] = $_REQUEST['account'];
            }
        }
           
        else {
            echo "Something went wrong";
        }
    }
}
       
// encode array to json and save to file
file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($decode, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
      
?>
    
    
<div class = "profile_body">
    <div class = "details">
        <p>Your Details</p>
            <div class = "profile_inner">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    Email<br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value = "" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>" >
                    <br><br>
                    Username<br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value = "" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>" >
                    <br><br>
                    Password<br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value = "" placeholder="••••••••••">
                    <br><br>
                    Account Type (Current: <?php echo $_SESSION['account_type']; ?>)<br><br>
                    <select name=account>
                    <?php 
                    if($_SESSION['account_type'] == "Local Guide"){?>
                         <option value="Local Guide">Local Guide</option>
                         <option value="Traveler">Traveler</option>
                         <?php
                    }
                    else{?>
                        <option value="Traveler">Traveler</option>
                        <option value="Local Guide">Local Guide</option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <br><br>
                    <button type = "submit" class="update_btn" name="update" >
                    Update
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JSON File: (users.json)

```
[
    {
        "userID": 1,
        "email": "yes@gmail.com",
        "username": "Hello2",
        "password": "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
        "account_type": "Traveler"
    },
    {
        "userID": 2,
        "email": "hello@gmail.com",
        "username": "Harry",
        "password": "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
        "account_type": "Local Guide"
    },
    {
        "userID": 3,
        "email": "kmsdnfkjnsf@gmail.com",
        "username": "Pony",
        "password": "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
        "account_type": "Local Guide"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is `$decode` and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `if/elseif`, only the block of first condition that succeeds will be executed.

You should use separate `if` conditions for each input, rather than `elseif`.

You also shouldn't report "Something went wrong" when the userID doesn't match. That's normal for all the array elements for other users.

Once you find the array element with the matching user ID, you can update it and then break out of the loop.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['update'])){
    foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['userID'] == $_SESSION['userID']) {
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
                $decode[$key]['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
            }
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['username'])){
                $decode[$key]['username'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
            }
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['password'])){
                $decode[$key]['password'] = sha1($_REQUEST['password']);
            }
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['account'])){
                $decode[$key]['account_type'] = $_REQUEST['account'];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```